# JSON object showing null pointer exception

Tags: java, android, sql, json

I want to post **data** to the `url` and getting `Null pointer exception` 
My `JSON` `URL` contains

```
{
  "Details":
    [
      {
        "Status":"NO UPDATES"
      }
    ]
}
```

I'm getting the error the line:

```
String status = object.getString("Status").trim(); //error Line
```

Full code:

```
btnPost = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnPost);

    btnPost.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnPost.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        @SuppressWarnings("null")
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0)
        {
            try
            {
                String postReceiverUrl = "http://";
                Log.v(TAG, "postURL: " + postReceiverUrl);
                // HttpClient
                @SuppressWarnings("resource")
                HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                // post header
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(postReceiverUrl);

                jsonobject.put("IDNo", IDNo.getText().toString());
                jsonobject.put("Position", Position.getText().toString());
                jsonobject.put("Data", Data.getText().toString());

                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

                String jsonResult = inputStreamToString(response.getEntity().getContent()).toString();

                Log.v("jsonResult",jsonResult);

                JSONObject object = new JSONObject(jsonResult);

                String status = object.getString("Status").trim();

                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Please wait...",100).show();

                if(status.toString().equals("SUCCESS"))
                {
                    Intent i = new Intent(LoginPage.this,MainActivity.class);
                    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
                if(status.toString().equals("FAILED"))
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Wrong Credentials",100).show();
                }

                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Details Inserted",100).show();
                }

            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            catch (JSONException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
            catch (ClientProtocolException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
            catch (IOException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }   


        }

    });
```

Comment: As you see in the response..Inside the JsonArray ("Details ") there is the ("Status") , so plz do proper parsing of the JSON

Comment: 'Details' is  a jsonArray not an object

Comment: Mounika  have Posted Edited  Json Parsing Code just replce it

Comment: @sunilsunny ..look at the response "Detail" is the "JsonArray " not "Jsonobject"

Comment: @RavindraKushwaha I didn't get you ..From my understanding It's an array containing single object.I think you and me are telling the same thing.Please read my comment one more time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code should be like this

```
 JSONObject object = new JSONObject(jsonResult);

            JSONOArray details = object.getJSONArray("Details");

           for (int i = 0; i < details.length(); i++) {
             JSONObject c = details.getJSONObject(i);

            String status = c.getString("Status");
            }
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Please wait...",100).show();
```

Comment: Thanku for ur response.Now iam getting a new error on 
JSONObject object = new JSONObject(jsonResult);


Error is org.json.JSONException: Value <!DOCTYPE of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject


Please help me out @curiousMind

Comment: http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/ @Mounika  try this link i think webservice's response is wrong

Comment: Iam getting the JSON response correctly, only that iam unable to convert jsonResult(which is a string) to JSONObject

Answer (score 1):

Do proper parsing of the `JSON` as , you see yours response:-

```
 { "Details":[{"Status":"NO UPDATES"}]}
```

So Firstly try to make the object of the `JSONObject` than after the `JSONArray` , look at below example:-

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonResult);
JSONArray detailsArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("Details");

String status = dataArray.getJSONObject(0).getString("status");

 Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Please wait...",100+status).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Modift `String status = object.getString("Status").trim();` to

```
String status = object.get("Details").getAsJsonArray()[0].getString("Status").trim();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `getString("Status")` which may return `null` if key is not available in JSON. I'd suggest you to use `optString("Status")` it'll return blank String if key is not available.

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(stringJSON);
JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.optJSONArray("Details");
if(jsonArray != null){
   for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
     JSONObject jObject = jsonArray.optJSONObject(i);
     if(jObject != null){
       String strStatus = jObject.optString("Status");
     }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this code**

```
 JSONObject object = new JSONObject(jsonResult);
 JSONArray array=object.getJsonarray("Details");
 for(int i=0;i<array.length();i++)
  {

   JSONObject innerObject=array.getJsonObject(i);
   String s= innerObject.getString("Status");

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If at any point in your code, `org.json.JSONObject json_object` becomes `null` and you wish to avoid `NullPointerException` (java.lang.NullPointerException), then simply check as following:

```
if(json_object == null) {
   System.out.println("json_object is found as null");
  }
  else {
       System.out.println("json_object is found as not null");
  }
```